# Angular 10 - Modules changes are not reflected after compilation

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

Here is my situation, I have a small project in **Angular10** where I have a couple of features, the problem occurs when I change a **Module**, after compiling **Angular** doesn't detect my changes.

The file is already created I'm just updating it.

This problem doesn't happens if I update any other typescript file, just happens with the modules.

For example, I have my **auth.module** where I have the **CommonModule** imported, I want to changed by a **SharedModule** (that contains the CommonModule, and some other components used by the **AuthModule**)

**auth.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {AuthComponent} from './auth.component';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AuthComponent],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([{path: 'auth', component: AuthComponent}]),
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class AuthModule {
}
```

If I start my application cannot resolve some components because those are not imported.

[image]

But, if I update my **auth.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AuthComponent],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([{path: 'auth', component: AuthComponent}]),
    SharedModule //This module is added
  ]
})
export class AuthModule {
}
```

Save and refresh the page, I'm still having the same error.

[image]

Also, if I check the code in the **Google developers tools** is updated.

[image]

The only way that my changes are taken is when I restart the server.
Of course the module (**auth.module**) is imported in the **app.module.ts**

I read some post that talks about a bug in the webpack, I tried that solutions with no luck

I attach some more information.

**package.json**

[image]

**folder structure**

[image]

Comment: Try stopping the server and try restarting it

Comment: If you have added a new file you have to restart the server so that file will be watched as well.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but the file is already there, I just change the import of CommonModule for SharedModule